# how can this script be done with an awk one-liner?

Tags: bash, awk, rename

I would like to substite more than one blank of the filenames of all files in a directory. So I want to create a rename script.

I have done this bash script and would like to ask if this could be done in an awk one-liner or more sophisticated.

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -name '*  *.*' -print > l1 
sed -i -e 's/^\|$/"/g'  l1
sed -e 's/  / /g' l1 >  l2 
sed -i -e 's/^/mv /g'   l1
pr -Tm l[12]
```

I have tried this with awk, but it I do get a wrong output.

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -name '*  *.*' -print > l1 
sed -i -e 's/^\|$/"/g'  l1
sed -e 's/  / /g' l1 >  l2 
awk -v FS=';' 'NR==FNR{  s[$1]=$0; next } END {print "mv "$0" "s[$1];}' l1 l2
```

my wrong output is just the `mv`and the line from l2.

Can one help me in finding the bug - what do I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: No. You can't use `awk` to **find** files. It's also not clear what it is you're trying to do. If you post some concise, testable sample input and expected output then we could probably help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to rename files to compress all chains of blanks in their names to 1? That'd be (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
while IFS= read -rd '' old; do
    new="${old// *( )/ }"
    mv -- "$old" "$new"
done < <(find "$1" -name '*  *.*' -print0)
```

No reason to involve awk or other commands.

Comment: Cool- that is really awesome how you do it! Thanks

Comment: `read -rd ''`, with the empty string as a separate argument. Then again, I suppose you could also use `for old in ./**/*'  '*; do`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it:
here

```
    awk -v FS=' ' 'NR==FNR{  s[$1]=$0; next }  {print "mv "s[$1]" " $0}' l1 l2
```

Comment: That's open to malicious code injection, variable expansion, etc. **IF** you were going to do this then the syntax would be `{print "mv -- \047"s[$1]"\047 \047" $0 "\047"}'`